# Unable to create "Qt Gui Application" with Visual Studio 2010 and Qt version 4.8.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am building a GUI application in which I have to use Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  I was told that the correct qt version to use with this VS version is 4.8.  I've downloaded Qt 4.8.0 using this link:

https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.0/

And I made this version the default in the VS Qt options menu.  However, when I try to create a new visual studio project, all of the module options are [greyed out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5rB.jpg)

Which in turn makes it impossible to create the project because upon clicking "next", the "Finish" button is also [greyed out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvY1g.jpg)  Any Idea of what's going on??

Comment: I'd suggest 1) upgrade your Visual Studio version to something not-ancient. 2) upgrade your Qt version to something not-outdated.   Just as a first step. You don't want to be stuck in the past.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'd like to but the dlls I need to make use of only work with VS 2010.  It's very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

With pre-compiled binaries (that is, you don't have to compile qt yourself) you can use Qt 5.5.1 with VS2010 that you can get from [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.5/5.5.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010-5.5.1.exe).

After that, i would create a simple project using qmake and specifying

```
TEMPLATE = VCAPP
```

that will tell the qmake (see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html)) to generate a .vcprojx file that you can use from VS2010.

Latest Qt version that supports VS2010 is 5.6.3 IIRC, however mind you that even that version is now EOL. (March 2019).

You should try to upgrade to 5.9 or 5.12 (however i am not sure that VS2010 will be able to support those since they rely pretty heavily on c++11 that VS2010 supported very lightly)

P.S. If you'r stuck with Qt4 then greatest version is 4.8.7 (VS2010 supported) that you could get from [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/qt-opensource-windows-x86-vs2010-4.8.7.exe)